# Stream data to web socket upon client request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, apache-kafka

I am working on a WebSocket application using Stomp in Spring boot. Currently working on sample applications to understand the message flows.

Here is my use case:

- The client display charts for different data.  eg. Total orders, Total revenue, etc.
- Once the user logs in to the client, the user can request different
  types of data.
- Upon receiving the request from the client for a particular type of
  data, the server should pull the requested data from the database,
  generate a model and push to the WebSocket every x minutes.
- Similarly, if the user sends the next request with the different datatype, the
  respective data should be pushed every x minutes

** Now here are queries I would like to clarify to go further and explore **

- Which are the different options I can go with for the above use case?
- Does Kafka support stomp? I am not familiar with Kafka at the moment but I intend to explore and learn it.
- It is still unclear to me if I can use Kafka as a stomp broker?!?
- Would I be able to continuously push datasets from db upon passing a specific param using kafka?
- Would it be possible to achieve this without using Kafka?

Could anyone throw some light on this, please?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not support STOMP. No, it doesn't seem like Kafka is required for this problem

If you want to use Kafka to pull from a database, you can find solutions like Debezium for this

Comment: The data has to be pulled from DB as per the "datatype" in websocket request and sent back to the websocket, as mentioned in the question. Debezium will have to be used along with Kafka if I need to pull from the database. Correct? Could you tell me if it is possible to achieve my use case by following using a basic websocket + kafka + debezium. The data that needs to be pulled from database is just 1 day worth of data. So I would also like to know if there are any other options available other than kafka debezium considering the fact that I am new to these technologies.

Comment: I would like to keep the minimum number of components in the application if possible since I've to come up with a solution quick as possible. Sad right now since I spent last week understanding stomp message flow :(

Comment: You should be able to use any database client. As I mentioned, Kafka isn't required. And I'm not sure STOMP capable servers are either. Websockets go directly between client and server

Comment: While looking into WS with STOMP, I was assuming Kafka would be the component responsible for fetching and routing 
 the data (continuously upon request) from DB to a service method that'd write to websocket. And thought I'll find out how to achieve it. but now that Kafka doesn't support stomp, I'm back to square one. Basically I am looking for the right components that'll help to achieve my usecase. I'm ready explore if anyone could tell me "these" are the combination I should go ahead with. Hope I have made use case clear for anyone to answer.

Comment: Just write the code... `for (ResultSet rs : db.findAll()) { ws.send(parse(rs)); }` . Not clear why you think Kafka would be needed

Comment: I was planning to use Kafka as a broker and tool to pull data using custom queries if needed. Since there is no support for stomp, I'm opting for RabbitMQ. Also, there was a requirement to get the last updated records only and not the whole load from DB. I read somewhere that it was possible using Kafka connect. I think I can get the same done using RabbitMQ. Supposing the user logs in at 8AM, the initial WS request would be served with the data from 12 am to 8 am and I can get the subsequent table inserts in the queue listener class which I can push to the socket. Could you please comment?

Comment: Never used Rabbitmq, but I know it's not the only solution that works with STOMP

Comment: I haven't used RabbitMQ either. But just diving in! Meanwhile, I'm stuck at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590670/unable-to-get-the-response-from-convertandsendtouser-stomp-websocket-sprin) right now. It would be helpful if you could please throw some light on this. Thanks for your time and comments.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you try to answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396425/websocket-implementation-using-apache-kafka-stomp-and-spring-boot-with-mutli-t